# downloading images using python and urllib.request

Tags: python, image, url

I have multiple urls in a csv file and I want to pull images from them. I download images every 1 second.
I am able to do so by following code. However, there are some situations that image corrupt of url is not providing an image. When those things happens code stops the process.
how could I code a logic that if the url is not working, it skips that particular site and continues the process?

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request

starttime = time.time()

from datetime import datetime

while True:
    print("tick")
    time.sleep(1.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 1.0))

    def url_to_jpg(i, url, file_path):


        now = datetime.now()
        filename = 'image'+str(now)+'.jpg'

        # print("now =", now)

        full_path = '{}{}'.format(file_path, filename)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
        print('{} saved.'.format(filename))

        # return None
    FILENAME='image_urls.csv'
    FILE_PATH='images/'
    urls= pd.read_csv(FILENAME)


    for i, url in enumerate(urls.values):
        url_to_jpg(i, url[0], FILE_PATH)
```

**Error that I get:**

```
  File "url_imageblock.py", line 38, in <module>
    url_to_jpg(i, url[0], FILE_PATH)
  File "url_imageblock.py", line 25, in url_to_jpg
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 276, in urlretrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 459, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 503, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into the `try-except` pattern?

Comment: Could you please provide some information about that? I am not familiar with that concept

Comment: Extra hint: put the function declaration outside (and before) the while loop

Comment: putting your function call inside a `try` block will prevent the code from stopping if a error occurs. You have to specify what to do in that case inside the corresponding `except` block. You can advise to code to output a custom error, some exception handling or just `pass`, which will just continue the code as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code following way, firstly add

```
import urllib.error
```

immediately after `import urllib.request` then change

```
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
    print('{} saved.'.format(filename))
```

to

```
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
    except (urllib.error.URLError, urllib.error.HTTPError):
        print('{} failure'.format(url))
    else:
        print('{} saved.'.format(filename))
```

In case of one of mentioned errors occuring this code will just print url followed by `failure`, if no error occurs it does print filename followed by `saved` as earlier. If you want to know more about urllib related errors read [`urllib.error` — Exception classes raised by urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#urllib.error.URLError)

Comment: I modified the code, but still it stops after a few minutes, I provided the error that it gives me. Please see the updated post.